# Codeigniter 4 modules loading constants

Tags: php, module, codeigniter-4

I have a project I am redesigning in codeigniter 4. The project will consist of several modules that can be turned on and off as required. For this project I am in need of constants that are loaded in and out according to the active modules in the project.

What I am looking for is the best way of achieving this. I have tried and failed in several ways.

First to scetch out my current setup of CI4

- Autoloading the modules in the Autoload.php config file
- Auto discover of config files in the Modules.php config file
- The modules folder is oudside of the app folder. And the folder consist of sub folders containing the actual modules. (example: modules/Admin and modules/Users)

I have tried adding constants to the Modules.php $aliases array. But as the constants file is not actualy a class file it does not get loaded.

I have also tried to use the following code inside of the app/Config/Constants.php. And it works to load the constants in but if I would disable a module those constants would still be loaded.

```
if (file_exists(ROOTPATH. 'modules')) {
$modulesPath = ROOTPATH.'modules/';
$modules = scandir($modulesPath);

foreach ($modules as $module) {
    if ($module === '.' || $module === '..') continue;
    if (is_dir($modulesPath) . '/' . $module) {
        $constantsPath = $modulesPath . $module . '/Config/Constants.php';
        if (file_exists($constantsPath)) {
            require($constantsPath);
        } else {
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

Any advice or diffrent path of thinking would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Another way I would suggest is to use CustomConfiguration as a service in CI4.

First Create a class with a method that will return the Modules path. So it will be as follows:

```
public class CustomConfiguration{

   //returns module paths.
   public function getActiveModulePaths(){
    return [
    'path1',
    'path2'
    ];
   }

  }
```

Now to use this CustomConfig as a service in CI4, you would need to extend the Service of CI4.

So at the following path app/Config/Services, you will need to create a singleton of the CustomConfiguration file:

```
   class Services extends CoreServices
{

       public static function customConfig($getShared = true)
       {
           if ($getShared)
           {
               return static::getSharedInstance('customConfig');
           }
    
           return new CustomConfiguration();
       }
}
```

This guarantees that whenever you call CustomConfiguration, it will always return a single instance of the custom configuration Class.

Now whenever you want to get the paths of your active modules, you could just call
the following:

```
service('customConfig')->getActiveModulePaths()
```

This will return the paths of the active modules.

Now to manipulate the paths of the active module in getActiveModulePaths you can either use the env file to fetch the paths dynamically or set it using Setter Method or DB Query.

Reference : https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/concepts/services.html?highlight=service